# How to write a code which allows user to enter number of bus tickets required and enter the price of a bus ticket, then find total cost

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
items = {
    "1 tickets" : 1.49, 
    "2 tickets" : 2.50, 
    "3 tickets" : 3.50, 
    "4 tickets" : 5.50, 
    "5 tickets" : 6.50, 
    "6 tickets" : 7.70
    }


shopping_cart = {}
total_cost = 0

while True:
    option = int(input("how much tickets would you like to buy: "))
    if option == 0: break

    elif option == 1: ticket = "1" 
    elif option == 2: ticket = "2"
    elif option == 3: ticket = "3" 
    elif option == 4: ticket = "4"
    elif option == 5: ticket = "5" 
    elif option == 6: ticket = "6"
    else:
        print("Not found")
        continue

    print(ticket)
    qnty = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
    shopping_cart[ticket] = qnty

    total = qnty*items[ticket]
    total_cost += total
    print("The price for these ticket(s) is: " + str(total))
    print('The total price is: %.2f' % total_cost)
    
    
print("\nThe total price  is %.2f " % total_cost)
print("hope you have a good journey")
```

This is my code, what's wrong with it?

I tried this and it keeps saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Home/Downloads/python.py", line 32, in <module>
    total = qnty*items[ticket]
KeyError: '1'
```

Comment: You have declared `items` as a _dict_ with keys like `"1 tickets"`, but you are using a key `1`.

Comment: Why are you using all those `if/elif` statements instead of something simple like `ticket = str(option)`?

Answer (score 0):

Your `items` dictionary has keys like `1 tickets`, `2 tickets`, not `1` or `2`, so when you try to access `items[ticket]` you are trying to access say `items['1']` when you actually want to access `items['1 tickets']`

Comment: Additionally, note that it may be considerably easier to change your dictionary to have the keys as integers 1,2,3,4,5, etc instead of these strings, to produce cleaner code in future.

Comment: @Mous. A dictionary with consecutive numerical keys can be expressed as a list much more efficiently